# Yii2-user without email varifivat email verification

Tags: authentication, user-registration, yii2-basic-app, yii2-user

I set yii2-user module to my basic template. And now I want user registration to be without email confirmation. I don't need email at all. How can I remove email and its setting from my app. Appreciate every answer!

Answer (score 0):

from the documentation
http://yii2-user.dmeroff.ru/docs/configuration

```
enableRegistration (Type: boolean, Default value: true)
```